# Uninstalled aplications still show launcher icons under installed aplications?

Tags: unity, icons, uninstall

The question is in the title, I always remove applications that I do not use after installing or upgrading, this includes games etc (wish it was possible to install Ubuntu with no applications then add the ones I require after, is this possible?)
Anyway after removing the applications they still show under the installed applications menu, if you click on them nothing happens but how do I get rid of the remaining icons?

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the top left Ubuntu icon (next to Applications) and select 'Edit Menus'

In the box that opens simply remove the tick from the icon you no longer wish to be displayed.